# Laravel: Make a Public Profile Page

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am making a laravel app that must have a public user profile page. The profile page that I currently have is a private one. How can I make the page public so that all the users can view all the profiles.

Here is the code:-

**In routes -> web.php**

```
Route::get('user/profile', 'UserProfileController@profile')->name('user.profile');
```

**In Http-> Controllers-> UserProfileController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserProfileController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    public function profile()
    {
        return view('user.profile');
    }


}
```

**In View -> user -> profile.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ Auth::user()->name }}'s Profile page</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    Hi, {{ Auth::user()->name }} This is a private profile page!!!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

The output looks like this
[image: The private profile view]

Comment: That code lacks essentials for what you want to do: your route should have an id or slug to identify the user whose profile you want to show. Then get the specific User's data in your `profile()` method, assign the data to your view, output the data in your `profile.blade.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**01. change router to**

```
Route::get('user/profile/{id}', 'UserProfileController@profile')->name('user.profile');
```

**02. in UserProfileController profile($id) method pass $id and middleware add except**

```
use App\User; 
class UserProfileController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => [ 'profile']]);
    }
    public function profile($id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);
        return view('user.profile', compact('user') );
    }

}
```

**03. In View -> user -> profile.blade.php **

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ $user->name }}'s Profile page</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    Hi, {{ $user->name }} This is a private profile page!!!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: sorry for responding late. I got the following error:-
Missing required parameters for [Route: user.profile] [URI: user/profile/{id}]. (View: /home/riwaj/Desktop/dmt-intern-manager/InternManager/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php)

Answer (score 1):

**add user id**

```
<a  href="{{ route('user.profile', auth()->user()->id )}}"></a>
```